# How to store UITextView data into NSMutablearray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This time I am having problems with not being able to store some data in an NSMutablearray.

The process is like this:

I click on a button that loads a UIPopOver and I make the selection of a product and its amount, through UIPIckerView,  when I click the Done button, the amount, product and total price appears on a UITextView. I'm ok with that.

The problem is that I need to store each selection from the UIPickerView in the NSMutablearray for a later calculation of the sum of all products selected, but it is not storing in the NSMutablerarray.

So, anyone could help???

```
-(void)donePressed{



//Cálculo do valor a pagar
float quantFlt = [[arrayQtdProdutos objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
float valorFlt = [[valorArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
float total = quantFlt * valorFlt;

_msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %@ - R$ %.2f",
        [arrayQtdProdutos objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]],
        [arrayOfCategories objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]],
        total];

_txtViewProdutos.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", _txtViewProdutos.text, _msg];

[arrayProdutosComprados addObject:_msg];
NSLog(@"%i", arrayProdutosComprados.count);

[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What is `msg`? Is it supposed to be a property?

Comment: 'msg'is a NSString that gets the amount, product and price of the selected row. And then is shown at the UITextView.

Comment: If you set a break point after you set `msg` I suspect that its going to be nil. So again, is it supposed to be a property?

Comment: Aparently yes, when I NSLog the NSMutablearray count it gets me '0'. As to whether should be a property or no, I think no.

Comment: You should add a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *msg` then change `msg = ` to `self.msg = ` And when you want to use it call `self.msg`

Comment: Unless you're using msg elsewhere as well, then just do NSString *msg = ...

Comment: I did both suggestions and still not working.

Comment: if arrayProdutosComprados has not been initialised with alloc/init (or new) then adding objects to it will go nowhere and its count will always be zero;

Comment: Hey guys I initialized the arrayProdutosComprados and it's not nil anymore, but still it does store only one object, it's not 'accumulating'  each selection I make through the UIPIckerView.

Comment: where are you initialising the array? if you're doing it each time you present the popover, then you're just creating a new array which will only have 1 entry

Comment: @SPA I was initializing the array inside the method that adds the object to it!!! Now I init in ViewDidLoad and everything is working fine!!! I will edit my question to display the final corrected code!!! Thank you SPA!!!

Comment: Instead of editing a title to say solved, you should accept an answer by clicking the little checkmark next to the answer that helped you most. If none of the answers particularly helped, you can write your own and accept that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code with the help of @SPA.

```
-(void)donePressed{

//Cálculo do valor a pagar
float quantFlt = [[arrayQtdProdutos objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
float valorFlt = [[valorArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
float total = quantFlt * valorFlt;

_msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %@ - R$ %.2f",
    [arrayQtdProdutos objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]],
    [arrayOfCategories objectAtIndex:[categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]],
    total];

_txtViewProdutos.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", _txtViewProdutos.text, _msg];

[arrayProdutosComprados addObject:_msg];
NSLog(@"%i", arrayProdutosComprados.count);

[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

arrayProdutosComprados = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SPA, it is more than likely that arrayProdutosComprados is nil.